# Java to Maven project conversion related details

Tags: java, maven-2, ejb-3.0

I am having a java project with a ant build file, using this ant file i create an ejb of the project and deploy it on the jboss server.
Now I am planning to use maven and convert this existing project which consist of nearly 28-30 jar's in its class path(jars related to ejb3, hibernate, jboss, etc).
I can easily do it using eclipse i.e right click project goto maven and click Conver to Maven.
A pom.xml is generated and the MavenClassPath Container is also added to the project.

**Now I want to know how to get rid of those 28-30 jar's present in the lib folder of the project and in the classpath. i.e. I want my pom.xml handle all the dependencies.
Does Maven provide any mechanism to achieve this goal while converting the project or I have to add all of these jar dependencies one by one manually in the pom.xml file.**

The intention of doing this is I want to have common maven remote repository where the jars will be stored and each developer machine will point to it through their maven project.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're after a repository manager like Nexus (I use Nexus, it seems to be the most popular http://nexus.sonatype.org/ ).

Nexus can be used as:

1. A proxy repository (for Maven Central, etc)
2. A repository for your own releases.

Nexus provides user management for your developers to release builds into the repo.

Developers will then point their Maven settings.xml file to your Nexus repository, and all their dependencies will come from here (Nexus will cache them).

I'm afraid you will have to configure the dependencies individually, but that is a good thing, because you should pay attention to what version ranges you are interested in for each dependency.

Any jars which can't be found in Maven Central, etc, you can add to your own Nexus repository .

Ofcourse there are alternatives to Nexus, but I haven't used any.

HTH

Answer (score 2):

The most important thing i can recommend is to use a Maven Repository Manager (Nexus, Artifactory or Achiva or other..).
Second your pom conversion via Eclipse shows me that you are not using an up-to-date Eclipse nor an up-to-date Maven Plugin for Eclipse. The best thing would be use Eclipse-Indigo (m2e is the newest and greatest).
Furthermore you have to go through all your jar's and add them step by step to you pom (dependencies) and see if your project can be compiled. This should be checked on command line not inside Eclipse.
After you got a working pom.xml file put it into your version control and check if you can remove some of your added dependencies based on transitive dependencies. After that you can finally delete your lib folder.